# Remove data with non-datetime input in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and I would like to filter the data based on the 'timestamp' column. Supposedly, if there are non-numerical data (which also mean *string*) in the *timestamp* column, I would like to extract the entire row of data and save it into another file.

[image: sample data]

Comment: Please don't show images! You are supposed to provide a [mcve], so that others could reproduce the problem. And **I** do not intend to write that by hand.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the values in the timestamps columns are timestamps by using the isinstance() function. This will allow you to store them in a list. Here is a way you could do it :

```
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp' : [datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1), 'aer', datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 1)]})

timestamps = [x for x in df['Timestamp'] if not(isinstance(x, datetime.date)) ]
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp' : timestamps }))
```

Out :

```
Timestamp
0   aer
```

Comment: I appear to have syntax error with last line of the code and I can't seem to understand why. For the second line, I'm able to get the output of all non-datetime type.

Comment: I had a few syntax errors I had not seen, I edited them the code should work now @progNerd